# MySQL Query Avg Date Range

Tags: mysql, average

I have a table with date and number column.
Couldn't find an example to get every 5 days' avg(number).

Could anyone help me this out?

Thanks.

Comment: you cant do that in a single query..use a script instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 SELECT AVG(number) AS average_number,
        FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(date)-MOD(TO_DAYS(date),5)) AS five_day_period_beginning
   FROM table
  GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(date)-MOD(TO_DAYS(date),5))
```

It will give you averages for five day chunks of time.

Comment: The five_day_period_beginning return 0000-00-00.